# Laravel $appends not showing in results

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to append a value to my model, but it isn't getting added. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Here is what I am defining:

```
protected $appends = ['hash'];

public function getHashAttribute(){
    return 'test';
}

public function scopeGetDeveloperGames($query, $userid){
    return $query
        ->join('game_info', 'games.game_id', '=', 'game_info.game_id')
        ->where('games.user_id', $userid)
        ->orderBy('games.created_at', 'desc')->limit(9);
}
```

When I do a dump, It doesn't show up in the results here is the call to the model:

```
$items = GamesModel::select('title', 'games.user_id', 'games.game_id', 'games.created_at', 'icon_large', 'icon_medium', 'icon_small', 'short_description')
->GetDeveloperGames($userid)
->get();
dd($items);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the docs

> Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will be included in both the model's array and JSON forms. Attributes in the appends array will also respect the visible and hidden settings configured on the model.

If you use toArray() or toJson():

```
$items = GamesModel::select('title', 'games.user_id', 'games.game_id', 'games.created_at', 'icon_large', 'icon_medium', 'icon_small', 'short_description')
->GetDeveloperGames($userid)
->get()
->toArray();
```

It will be visible.

Comment: Okay, I must have missed that I needed to call `toArray()` but that seems to fix it!

Answer (score 3):

This is for future in case someone else comes to this page with a similar (not exact) issue via google: 
I had similar issues, turns out I was not using Eloquent correctly, I had appends in my model - EventyTypes but I was getting data using `$eventTypes = DB::table('event_types')->get()`; which was incorrect. I then modified it to  `$eventTypes = EventTypes::get();` and it worked. This makes sense since the appends is in Model you should get data from model and not using DB.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly different but similar issue I ran into around this was using the `with()` method.

I had `Event::with(['event_types:id,name,url'])` where url was defined by `getUrlAttribute()` in the `EventType` model. But this wasn't working because my syntax `event_types:id,name,url` attempts to load specific columns which isn't compatible.

To fix the issue I removed this syntax and just did `Event::with(['event_types'])` which loaded everything as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays) and [`toJson()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json) aren't cutting it and you need your custom model attributes to appear using `getAttributes()`:

```php
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['foobar'];

public function getFoobarAttribute()
{
    return 'abc';
}

protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::retrieved(function($model) {
        // Oh no, we're doing something slightly outside of Laravel's
        // walled garden and we're subjecting ourselves to the dire, dire 
        // consequences. /s
        foreach ($model->appends as $append) {
            $model->original[$append] = $model->$append;
            $model->attributes[$append] = $model->$append;
        }
    });
}
```